# std::move semantic vs. create class directly inside a push_back

Tags: c++, copy, move

To avoid copy process, I know that we can use `move` semantic to do.

Let's say I have a customised class or a standard math class `Vector3d` from `Eigen` lib. For the following cases, say if I want to create an object and put it into a `std::vector`, how to do it correctly to save the unnecessary copy process?

```cpp
vector<Vector3d> vec;

auto x = Eigen::Vector3d(a,b,c);
vec.push_back(x); //                     case 1 -- copy

vec.push_back(Vector3d(a,b,c)); //       case 2 -- construct and copy? unnecessary copy process?
vec.push_back(move(Vector3d(a,b,c)); //  case 3 -- is this the correct way to do it?
```

Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: (2) and (3) are both rvalues and therefore identical; in (3) the `std::move` is redundant as it turns an rvalue into an rvalue.  `std::vector::emplace_back` would probably be better - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back as it avoids constructing the temporary entirely.

Comment: @RichardCritten I know I can do `emplace_back(a,b,c)` which will avoid the temporary entry. But isn't `emplace_back(Vector3d(a,b,c))` and `push_back(Vector3d(a,b,c))` the same?

Comment: `emplace_back(Vector3d(a,b,c))` will only work if `Vector3d` has a copy constructor as the parameters to `emplace_back` as passed to the constructor of `Vector3d`

Comment: Sidenote: `std::move` doesn't move anything, it's basically just a cast. Also since `Vector3d` probably doesn't own any resources, moving it is no different from copying it.